# FindContours() in OpenCV produces a polygon when it should produce a polyline

Tags: opencv

I am trying to converts canny edges to geometry in opencv (which I can then manipulate with Shapely). I am using FindContours which works great when there is a polygon in the middle of the image, but if the edges intersect the border, it returns a polygon which follows the length of the edge and back again, e.g.

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1]]
```

Currently my existing workflow looks something like this:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(frame, 100, 200)
contours = cv2.FindContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Example of input image:

[image: Example Image 1]

Comment: can `cv2.copyMakeBorder` help you?

Comment: Presumably your image is made of rectangles that are easy to binarize. Applying Canny just spoils them.

Comment: The image was a simplified example, the real images processed are not strait edges nor vertical / horizontal

Comment: I too would recommend that you present the task, not just the problem with your chosen solution, i.e. post some unfiltered source pictures -- no, OpenCV, to my knowledge, does not have any ridge following method except Canny, and that merely returns a mask, not a list of points (even though the Canny algorithm could in principle...)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have reworded my question and added an example of an input image

Comment: Canny followed by findContours will give you one closed contour around each _line_. it will put one half of the contour on each side of the line. you should consider that to be nonsense. canny is counterproductive. for that image, you should simply threshold. -- findContours considers contours around white objects on a black background. if you want to, you can analyze each contour and split and strip points that lie on the image edge.

Comment: You are correct, that is exactly what is happening. So are you suggesting to iterate through the points in each contour and trim the second line? is it safe to assume that a contour will always start and end at the border?

Comment: Perhaps a better question is, will the contour always start at the beginning of the line? Or do I need to consider moving the start position to the beginning of the line?

Comment: contour points are ordered but there is no "beginning". contours are closed curves, cyclic. the "first" point in a points list is arbitrary. -- I would suggest that you express a predicate that says whether any point is "on the edge of the picture". then label all contour points like that (boolean). then you can `np.roll` and split to taste.

Comment: I have written an implementation of this by iterating through the line and determining whether p[i-1] == p[i+1] to find the index where to split. This works for most polylines however there are a two cases I have found where this fails... 1) When there is more than one end point (e.g. imagine a T shaped line) and 2) Some end points don't have exactly the same adjacent points (i.e. [0,1] [0,2] [1,1]). this is getting a bit messy and I don't particularly trust this algorithm :/ It's a real shame there isn't a method to convert pixels to polylines in opencv, it seems like this should be inclusive